# ReactJS not rendering my text(I am a noob just started learning)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

This is my html

````
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="root"></div>
   <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
   ```
Javascript

import React from "react"
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"

ReactDOM.render(
   <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
   document.getElementById('root')
 );
````

The problem is that there are no problems and nothing shows up on the output as wrong. I made sure to save my code and rebooted VS code a bunch of times. I installed all the libraries and was following a tutorial. Then for some reason it isn't working.

Comment: Where did you make these files? Have you made sure that you made the folder using "npx create-react-app ." ? That way all the react modules get installed which will allow the html to be written in jsx.Then the best way is to make a component or function where you include the html into the return section.

Comment: How should I do that

Comment: The simplest way when you get started is first to open up your VSC or whatever. Then into the terminal, enter "npx create-react-app {you filename}". Then there should be a folder with all the mudules, a public folder and a src folder. In the src folder, you can delete all the text and webkit pages (at the beginning). Then in the App.js page, delete the boilerplate html within the "return" which already exists in the file. Then, all you have to do is write your html and it should work

Comment: You should try also explaining in your question how is it that your are importing the libraries.